# Dynamic class method invocation in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Like the question at [Dynamic class method invocation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251485/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-php) I want to do this in Dart.

```php
var = "name";
page.${var} = value;
page.save();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Be sure to green checkmark one of those answers! They're both correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several things you can achieve with [Mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/be/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html).

Here's an example how to set values of classes and how to call methods dynamically:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Page {
  var name;

  method() {
    print('called!');
  }
}

void main() {
  var page = new Page();

  var im = reflect(page);

  // Set values.
  im.setField("name", "some value").then((temp) => print(page.name));

  // Call methods.
  im.invoke("method", []);
}
```

In case you wonder, `im` is an [`InstanceMirror`](https://api.dart.dev/be/169966/dart-mirrors/InstanceMirror-class.html), which basically reflects the `page` instance.

There is also another question: [Is there a way to dynamically call a method or set an instance variable in a class in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525929/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-call-a-method-or-set-an-instance-variable-in-a-cla)

Comment: Is anyone know how to do this in Flutter? In flutter we cannot import dart:mirros package :/

Comment: @KavindaJayakody
Flutter forbids using mirrors and html libraries from Dart due to performance premise, using them would drastically impact widget rebuild time. You can read more about this [at Flutter FAQ page](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Dart Mirror API](https://api.dart.dev/be/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) to do such thing. Mirror API is not fully implemented now but here's how it could work :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Page {
  String name;
}

main() {
  final page = new Page();
  var value = "value";

  InstanceMirror im = reflect(page);
  im.setField("name", value).then((_){
    print(page.name); // display "value"
  });
}
```

Comment: The call to `Futures.wait()` makes little sense here. You can omit it and the result is the same. `Futures.wait()` returns a `Future` that completes when the given actions complete, so, you really have to write a `.then()` to get it properly to work. Of course it now works by luck since the operations happen to be non-async :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am new to Future usage and I confused with the `await` proposal www.dartbug.com/104

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/serializable)

For example:

```
import 'package:serializable/serializable.dart';

@serializable
class Page extends _$PageSerializable {
  String name;
}

main() {
  final page = new Page();
  var attribute = "name";
  var value = "value";

  page["name"] = value;
  page[attribute] = value;

  print("page.name: ${page['name']}");
}
```