# how can i to instance an object by the classname in dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

i know there is a way to create objects in dart by the class names using dart:mirrors
but i couldn't make it myself (I'm a beginner in dart), so please can anyone show me how to do it by an example ?
the code i want to do is something like this process (if it's possible!):

```
var myClass = getClassbyClassname("className");
//myClass now is an object of the indicated className
```

and please how can i use the methods inside myClass dynamically? for example

```
myClass.doMethod("myMethod",argumentsHere);
//myClass will execute myMethod
```

thank you in advence!

Comment: Invoke using mirrors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293345/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-dart

Comment: @Fox32 you're my hero thank you a lot