# Change the function name like Python in Flutter

Tags: python, flutter

I have found a piece of code about Globals in Python that `globals()['use_variables_as_function_name']()`  is equivalent to `use_variaable_as_function_name()` .In fact, is there any codes in Flutter could do the same thing like Python do?

Comment: Flutter apps use the Dart programming language, so you should search for dynamic method calling in Dart. [Here's the first post that came up when I searched it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293345/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-dart) - I'm not literate in Dart, though, so I don't know if this is actually a duplicate

Comment: There is no automatic way to map `String`s to functions without reflection.  You would have to create such a mapping yourself manually.